How to set a shortcut in finder for the "Public" folders?
I notice that OneDrive add its folder to "Finder->Go",just like this

It means there is a way to change the folders under Finder's Go Tags.So how to realize it?
I tried to defaults read some plist files.But no one works.

I see Dropbox and Google Drive in my "Go" menu. Guessing this is done by macOS for any cloud service using the File Provider framework (e.g. Dropbox, Google, OneDrive).
